# How to parse and chage content of external link in dokuwiki plugin

Tags: parsing, wiki, dokuwiki

I was trying to do it like this in my Plugin.

```
function getType(){ return 'substition'; }
function getSort(){ return 299; } 
function connectTo($mode) { 
  $this->Lexer->addSpecialPattern('@.+?@',$mode,'plugin_externallink');
}

function render($mode, &$renderer, $data) {
  print_r($data);
}
```

but patten doesn't match anything.

Here is markup example:

```
[[http://@testDomain@/test|testDomain]]
```

Comment: There is one important thing to note, the DokuWiki lexer is sequential. You cannot match something like `@.+?@` inside a link, because the internallink pattern will already eat up the whole `[[something]]` block. This is not a matter of priority, but just because it will match earlier in the input string.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid the content of `[[ ]]` is handled by either the [internallink mode](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/b63529ad89f66ca4de0b4b6003892ac7fd71653c/inc/parser/parser.php#L884) or the external link.

Those modes aren't configured to accept any other mode (because of the implementation of `accepts` which [doesn't accept anything](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/b63529ad89f66ca4de0b4b6003892ac7fd71653c/inc/parser/parser.php#L172) here).

What you could do is:

- Match the whole pattern. ie: not just what's inside the `@..@`, but what's inside the `[[ ]]`
- Define a priority smaller than the one of the `internallink` (300) and the one of the externallink (330). (Hence, 299 is already fine)

To handle it, you might then want to rely on the `internallink` [method](https://github.com/splitbrain/dokuwiki/blob/b63529ad89f66ca4de0b4b6003892ac7fd71653c/inc/parser/renderer.php#L215) of the `renderer`

Comment: As whole pattern you mean something like this `\[\[@.+?@\]\]` ?

Comment: maybe rather something like `\[\[.*@.+?@.*\]\]` (or maybe `[^[]*` instead of `.*`). You may also want to include some lookahead tricks